# ASP.Net MVC 2 Application Login page as startuppage

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

Dear All,
I want to disable anonymous access to my MVC 2 application for that I add below code in web.config file `<deny users="?" />
     <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>`
After that application start with login page but it is not taking masterpage and css styles

This is Login page code

`<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

Log On

### Log On

Please enter your username and password. <%: Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") %> if you don't have an account.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

`

can someone direct me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `<deny users="?" />` in ASP.NET MVC. Use the `[Authorize]` attribute to decorate controllers/action that need to be protected. So for example if you wanted to protect all controllers you could have a base controller which will be decorated with this attribute:

```
[Authorize]
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{
    protected BaseController() {}
}
```

and then have other controllers derive from it. Obviously the `LoginController` shouldn't derive from this base controller as it need to show the login form without requiring authentication.

Comment: Mr Darin Dimitrov, Thank you very much its working perfect :)